# MFC App hangs after CSingleLock Lock()

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

```
void CADAPBatchView::AddMsgToStatusWindow(const CString& strMsg)
{
    CString strTemp;
    CString strEngineStatusEntry;
    int nLinesToScrollPast = 0;
    int nTrimPos = 0;
    strEngineStatusEntry.Format(_T("%s %s\n"), CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format( _T( "%H:%M:%S" )), strMsg);

    CSingleLock singleLock( &m_csStatusMsg );
    singleLock.Lock();

    if (m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.GetLineCount() > 200)
    {
        m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.SetReadOnly(FALSE);   //remove readonly so SetSel will work
        m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.SetSel(0, m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.LineIndex(100));
        m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.Clear();
        m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.SetReadOnly(TRUE);    //put back readonly
    }

    int nBegin;
    nBegin = m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.GetTextLength();
    m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.SetSel(nBegin, nBegin);   // Select last character
    m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.ReplaceSel(strEngineStatusEntry);          // Append, move cursor to end of text
    //m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.SetSel(-1,0);             // Remove Black selection bars
    //nBegin = m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.GetTextLength(); // Get New Length
    //m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.SetSel(nBegin,nBegin);    // Cursor to End of new text

    nLinesToScrollPast = m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.GetLineCount() - 9 - m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.GetFirstVisibleLine();
    m_wndEngineStatusMsgs.LineScroll( nLinesToScrollPast );


    if (m_wndChkStatusMsgLog.GetCheck() == 1)
    {
        WriteToLogFile(strEngineStatusEntry);
    }

    return;
}
```

I have attached the code showing the two threads. At the time of the crash from the dump files I see that The main thread is at the line just after the `singlelock.Lock()`. The second thread is at the line starting with `nLinesToScrollPast`. I'm thinking a deadlock situation has occurred but don't know how. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't attach links to pictures but copy'n'paste the minimal code that is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suspect that all of those `SetSel`, `ReplaceSel` etc. are wrapping `SendMessage` which, when called from the worker thread, will wait forever for the blocked main thread to process them.

Comment: First, you have not attached any code, only a link to a bitmap (which will not be valid in future, so this question will not make sense in future). Second you have not shown any code for your second thread. And regarding your deadlock: start the program in a debugger and look at the callstack for every thread, so you will see why you get a deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to make method `AddMsToStatusWindow` thread-safe in order to call it from other threads. Your problem is that only the main application thread is allowed to interact with the GUI otherwise you'll end up having problems with your message pump (because you do lock `SendMessage`). So your design is wrong. You should create guarded message queue based on `CCriticalSection`. So the thread would put the message to a queue and then call `PostMessage` to notify the main thread that data/message has been put to a queue. The main thread will populate the data from this queue in message handler.